# Is it dangerous to use dynamic database TEST_NAME in Django?

Tags: django, testing, jenkins

We are a small team of developers working on an application using the PostgreSQL database backend. Each of us has a separate working directory and virtualenv, but we share the same PostgreSQL database server, even Jenkins is on the same machine.

So I am trying to figure out a way to allow us to run tests on the same project in parallel without running into a database name collision. Furthermore, sometimes a Jenkins build would fail mid-way and the test database doesn't get dropped in the end, such that subsequent Jenkins build could get confused by the existing database and fail automatically.

What I've decided to try is this:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # the usual lines ...
        TEST_NAME: '{user}_{epoch_ts}_awesome_app'.format(
            user=os.environ.get('USER', os.environ['LOGNAME']),
            # This gives the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch
            epoch_ts=int((datetime.utcnow() - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds())
        ),
        # etc
    }
}
```

So the test database name at each test run *most probably* will be unique, using the username and the timestamp. This way Jenkins can even run builds in parallel, I think.

It seems to work so far. But could it be dangerous? I'm guessing we're safe as long as we don't try to import the project settings module directly and only use django.conf.settings because that *should* be singleton-like and evaluated only once, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing something similar and have not run into any issue. The usual precautions should be followed:

1. Don't access `settings` directly.
2. Don't cause the values in `settings` to be evaluated in a module's top level. See the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#use-of-django-conf-settings) for details. For instance, don't do this:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings

   # This is bad because settings might still be in the process of being
   # configured at this stage.
   blah = settings.BLAH

   def some_view():
       # This is okay because by the time views are called by Django, 
       # the settings are supposed to be all configured.
       blah = settings.BLAH
   ```
3. Don't do anything that accesses the database in a module's top level. The [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) warns:

   > If your code attempts to access the database when its modules are compiled, this will occur before the test database is set up, with potentially unexpected results. For example, if you have a database query in module-level code and a real database exists, production data could pollute your tests. It is a bad idea to have such import-time database queries in your code anyway - rewrite your code so that it doesn’t do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the time, you could use the Jenkins executor number (available in the environment); that would be unique enough and you wouldn't have to worry about it changing.

As a bonus, you could then use --keepdb to avoid rebuilding the database from scratch each time... On the downside, failed and corrupted databases would have to be dropped separately (perhaps the settings.py can print out the database name that it's using, to facilitate manual dropping).